# 3rd Party Code Coverage is below 75%, is this bad? What to do?

Tags: apex, code-coverage, unit-test

We have a bunch of installed apps which are just killing our code coverage. We're now down to only 77%, and all of the classes which are below 75% are from installed apps.

Has anybody else had this problem ? If so, what did you do (outside of uninstalling the apps) ? These are big name type apps also - Facebook, Twitter etc. They're not just fly-by-night vendors who don't feel like doing their test coding.

Is there anything to do for this ? How did you handle it ?

Thank you.

Comment: These are apps that are unmanaged code (no namespace) right?

Comment: They're managed. I am unable to see the code.

Comment: Oh. I'm confused then as I was under the impression that such classes are not run and not counted in the local coverage stats; they are run and counted/verified as part of the managed package publishing process. Hopefully someone else has a better understanding of what you are experiencing...

Comment: Are you sure ? I am looking at two of our environments, one production and one a sandbox. There's a really big difference between the two, and the really the main thing different between the two is the third party code.

Comment: Keith, you are correct.  Managed package code is not included in the required code coverage calculation for deployment.  The 75% requirement is on all Apex code in your org's namespace.  Managed code has its own namespace, so it is not included.
When deploying to production, all tests in your org's namespace will be run.  Managed tests will not be run by default.

Comment: When you use Run all tests, it runs the tests that are included in managed packages, if test methods in the managed packages fails, then the code coverage is effected.  This however, will not prevent deployment to your org, when deploying to your org, only your org namespace tests are run, so this excludes managed package test code.  So although you may get a coverage of under 75% when you 'Run allTests, this is misleading, as you can still deploy if its managed package code thats dropping your coverage.

Comment: What is likely causing this drop in coverage is some Validation rules that have been added to your org since the installation of the managed package, which is causing test methods within the managed test code to fail.

Comment: Ah, ok. So the managed packages DO affect the overall percentage I see after I Run All Tests - correct ? It just won't prevent me from deploying. Is this correct ?

Comment: Correct.  I will add an answer with something for you to try in a moment.

Comment: Then how can I get a code coverage percentage read of only my local code ? That's the percentage I am truly concerned about since it will prevent me from deploying.

Comment: Just added an answer.  hope that helps

Answer (score 16):

A few things to note here.

- Managed package code is not included in the required code coverage
  calculation for deployment.
- The 75% requirement is on all Apex code    in your org's namespace.
  Managed code has its own namespace, so it is    not included.
- When deploying to production, all tests in your org's    namespace
  will be run. Managed tests will not be run by default

When documentation states that you must have 75% code coverage in order to deploy, it can be misleading.  You must have 75% code coverage on code with *YOUR* orgs namespace.  Managed Packages have their own namespace, so the test run on that code isn't evaluated on deployment.

A caveat here is that if you choose to 'Run All Tests' in your org, that does include managed package test code.  So you could have 80% coverage on all your code, but when you 'Run All Tests' it shows you have 68% coverage.  This would make you think you would not be able to deploy to this org, but you can, as the coverage for your org namespace is 80%, not the 68% its showing you.

Salesfroce accounts for this by giving you a link to estimate your code coverage, which will exclude the managed package test code.  I fully admit this is not extremely evident in the UI as they really only tell you this on the tooltip bubble.

Try using the Estimate your organizations code coverage link.  you will likely get a higher number that when you 'Run all tests'.

[image]

As a side note, there are lots of things that could have 'broken' the test code in the managed package, but I find many times its as simple as one or more validation rules that were added to the org after the managed package was installed.  Imagine the Package test method inserts a test Acccount.  Now imagine after the installation of the package you added a validation rule that ensures an account has a picklist value on a certain field chosen.  the managed package test code will now fail, which effects the test coverage.  I know thats not what you were asking, but just thought I would add that as some additional info.

> EDIT

You can also chose to run only the code from your Org namespace which will exclude the managed package code.  If you go to Setup -> Develop -> Apex test Execution.  Click the 'Select Tests' button and there is a drop down for either all namespaces, or just your namespace.  This will allow you to run all tests only on your code.

[image]

> EDIT

You can no longer clear code coverage from the **Setup -> Develop -> Apex Classes** menu as you could before.  You know need to use the developer console for this.

https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000T07jAAC

Comment: thanks again SF_Ninja. I see the low percentage when I hit the "Estimate.." link. But it must be due to the 3rd party apps because they are the only classes with anything below 75% after I do a Run All Tests. I don't get it.

Comment: Did you use the compile all classes link prior to the estimation?

Comment: No - I didn't. I just did now. Should I do another Run All Tests now ? Will that affect it ?

Comment: It may, give it a try

Comment: fyi : I ran the compile and then did a Run All Tests and I'm still at the same Code Coverage %. Thanks again SF_Ninja.

Comment: I added a bit more to the answer, perhaps that will help

Comment: Thanks again SF_Ninja. I'll definitely try that. Is there a way for me to set the code coverage back to 0% and then just run the tests I want ?

Comment: It is a known issue with Winter 14 thast there is no longer a 'Clear Code Coverage' button.  You know need to use the dev console for this.  Another example of SF trying to push the Dev console on us.  https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000T07jAAC

Comment: I have a response to SF_Ninja's comment "It is a known issue with Winter 14 that there is no longer a 'Clear Code Coverage' button. You know need to use the dev console for this. Another example of SF trying to push the Dev console on us. success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000T07jAAC" If you go to Develop -> Apex Test Execution -> View Test History -> Clear Test Results. I believe this is what he is looking for but I may be mistaken.

Answer (score 1):

When using Ant to deploy unmanaged code, the [documentation](http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000003620&language=en_US) is clear about the **runAllTests** flag that:

> In Production - if set to false, then managed package tests will not run but every other test will run.
>   In Sandbox - if set to false, no tests will run.